# JavaScript: Open a new tab to a specific google image search

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to make it easier to help my users find icons for their 'web desktop' they create at my website:

[Booky:  Your Personal Bookmark Web Desktop](http://www.bookydesktop.com)

I looking for line of url that would open a specific 'google image search', for example:

if you type in google images: facebook 128 png icon

What would the url look like?

Right click on a bookmark and you'll see what I'm getting at.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://www.google.com/search?q=facebook+128+png+icon&hl=en&site=imghp&tbm=isch

You may want to look into the [Custom Search API](https://developers.google.com/custom-search/v1/overview) instead.

Comment: That link helps.  I can just parse in what I want and let Google take over from there.  I like the idea of the api, but 100 results comes fast.  I can't expect to charge users fresh out of the gate like this.      If there were a way to trade for ad clicks, I think it would fair.

Comment: I've tested the string you gave and just replacing facebook with the relevant text.  It opens a tab in Chromium, but does not perform search until you press seach again.  Firefox will actually go right to the search.  Any idea why this is happening?  Maybe this should be a different question, not sure.

Comment: Can you post the URL you're using? I was using Chromium when I tried out the URL I posted, and it worked.

Comment: This one opens tab and search terms are in the search bar, but no icons show until you hit search button: http://www.google.com/search?q=facebook+128+png+icon&hl=en&site=imghp&tbm=isch

Comment: This is what it changes to when I hit the search button: https://www.google.com/search?q=facebook+128+png+icon&hl=en&site=imghp&tbm=isch&biw=1280&bih=912&sei=ZS45UZyaMObgyQHBtIDYDw  The first works in Firefox right away.

Answer (score 0):

You may use [Google image search API](https://developers.google.com/image-search/).

> Important: The Google Image Search API has been officially deprecated as of May 26, 2011. It will continue to work as per our deprecation policy, but the number of requests you may make per day may be limited. We encourage you to upgrade to the [Custom Search API](https://developers.google.com/custom-search/v1/overview), which now supports image search.

Comment: Thanks.  I'm going to have to search over the documentation and make sure it won't limit the ability for users to search for icons without asking them to pay money.  This would severely complicate my aims.  I hope to operate a free website and generate money from ads.